# How to disable mouseover for a note in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet in excel with some vba code that makes a note show up when I navigate the cursor to the cell and turn off when I navigate the cursor away.

However, the note still shows up when the mouse is hovering over the cell, which I want to prevent.

Is there a way to disable this mouseover functionality without disabling the note feature entirely?

Comment: Comment or note?

Comment: Sorry, technically note.

Comment: You can use `Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlNoIndicator` to prevent the mouse over effect.  Whether this affects your code, will depend on your code...